# Brief characterizations of AIC and BIC: how helpful are they?

Tags: interpretation, aic, bic, information-criteria

I have found the following one-sentence characterizations of AIC and BIC in a lecture note:

> 1. AIC estimates the degree to which the predictive accuracy of the model will generalize to new data.

> 2. BIC assesses the "information lost" by replacing the data with a model of the data.

Obviously, these are not rigorous characterizations and they are not meant as such. But I wonder if they catch the essence of AIC and BIC and help discriminate between them at all.

**Q1:** Would replacing *AIC* with *BIC* in the first characterization above make it less valid / less helpful?
**Q2:** Would replacing *BIC* with *AIC* in the second characterization above make it less valid / less helpful?

Comment: perhaps the question should be: what is the mathematical identity underlying each?

Comment: @user551504, thank you for your suggestion. The identities can be checked in a textbook, on Wikipedia or in other threads on CV. Meanwhile, my actual questions are the ones I have posed. That is, they deal with particular interpretations and their discriminatory qualities.